# difference between telerik mvc controls suite paid/opensource

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2, telerik-grid

what is the difference between the paid version and open source telerik controls for mvc 2/3?

Comment: I didn't know Telerik released an Open Source control suite. If they did, I am sure they have the legalese/differences posted somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we have been using telerik controls for asp.net mvc for an year now. they work great and you can post issues on their forums and most of the problems are solved there. they also have a code library where you can find code samples. the only thing is that if you want to create a support ticket and want telerik team to see it on priority then you have to pay the support cost otherwise its just free. but from our experience i can tell you that we weer stuck about dozen times (in the beginning) but never had to create a support ticket problems were solved at forums. i will strongly urge you to use these controls. they are great and can save you lot of coding and time

Comment: so there is no cost involved when you use the open source version?

Comment: Be careful: according to their [licensing FAQ](http://www.telerik.com/purchase/faqs/aspnet-mvc.aspx), you need to comply with the terms of the GPLv2. Which means that if you distribute your application to anyone, you need to also distribute the source under a GPLv2 license!

Answer (score 1):

Another thing...you may want to read the fine print to check me on this, but I believe that the open source version can only be used for an internal application or another open source application that you are developing.  If you want to sell or use your product on a commercial basis, then you have to buy the full license.

Answer (score 0):

There is mainly no major difference in terms of functioanlity.
The basic thing is that u can't get support from Telerik company if something stops working.

I am already using Telerik open source MVC toolkit in my project and is working fine.

Comment: There is a major difference: your application needs to be licensed under the GPLv2. This isn't a problem for internal apps, but if you want to distribute your app you need to distribute your source code too.